# Databinding generate included layouts as view in aar file

Tags: android, data-binding, aar, android-viewbinding

My project contains multiple modules, and I am using `aar` files of other modules contains custom views and components. so I have an XML in .aar and I want to use it in my project.
Of course, I can but DataBinding doesn't generate it in the generated file, so I don't have access to XML's components and widgets.

My fragment's XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <!-- Comes from AAR file -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        layout="@layout/simple_tool_bar" />
```

Simple toolbar is:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/simple_tool_bar_height"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/primary" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And Databinding generated file is:

```
public abstract class FragmentTestBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
  
  @NonNull
  public final View toolbarLayout;
```

So as you can see in the generated file `toolbarLayout` is an instance of View but it should be `SimpleToolBarBinding`.
When you are working on a project that contains modules instead of .aar it everything is working well, but after generating the .aar file and use it in another project it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a sample project so that I can look into it?

Comment: I have the same problem, is there a solution?

Comment: Not sure, you can also test with <Merge/> as the first element of your XML. then share the result here please

Answer (score 2):

***Conclude:***
The Android Gradle Plugin (version: 7.2.0) doesn't support to generate the matched type of `XxxBinding` when the layout file is in class (aar).

***Reason:***

**I compared the gradle tasks of using module's layout file with using aar's layout file.**

We missed following gradle tasks:

```
:module:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
:module:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug
:module:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
```

**And analyzed the related `ViewBinding` AGP source code, in the function of `android.databinding.tool.writer.ViewBinderKt#toViewBinder`**

```
        // Check to make sure that the ID matches a binding. Ignored tags like <merge> or <fragment>
        // might have an ID but not have an actual binding. Only use ID if a match was found.
        val rootBinding = bindings.singleOrNull { it.id == id }
        if (rootBinding != null) {
            return RootNode.Binding(rootBinding)
        }
```

If the `binding` doesn't in the binding list, it would be regarded as `View`.

***Workaround***

Using the function of `ViewBinding.bind(view: View)` to inflate the `XxxBinding` manually.

**layout file**

```xml
<!-- activity_awesome.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <include android:id="@+id/includes" layout="@layout/included_buttons" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  
<!-- included_buttons.xml 在aar中-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/include_me" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Generated Code**

```kotlin
// Activity.kt
class Activity {
    private val includedButtonsBinding :IncludedButtonsBinding 
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val rootBinding = ActivityAwesomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        includedButtonsBinding = IncludedButtonsBinding.bind(ActivityAwesomeBinding.includes)
        return rootBinding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!